# reconstituting an object from console output

Tags: ruby, rails-console

Is there a way to convert console output like `"#<BigDecimal:6999660,'0.1E3',9(36)>"` back into the original object? The integer form of this number is 100, but I have no way of knowing that when I see it returned by RSpec (for example).

Comment: No, not unless you write code to parse it yourself, which is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Manually you can just call `BigDecimal.new('0.1E3').to_s` in a rails console and get the number: `=> "100.0"`.

In that example the E notation is really simple, you just have to move the . by the number after E positions. If it's > 0 move it to the right, if it's smaller < 0 move it to the left. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation for a more detailed explanation.

`0.1E3 == 1.0E2 == 10.0E1 == 100.0E0 == 100.0`

Comment: Is that really all there is to it? I thought those other fields might be important.

Comment: Yes, have a look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-inspect to see a more detailed explanation of what you get.